# Conditionally emit observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx, ngrx-store

We have an Angular 4 app with Redux (ngrx 4).

We keep the info "isLoggedIn" in the ngrx/store, and when we issue a call to the http, we have to first check if he's authenticated or not.

What we're struggling with is the implementation of the service making the http calls:

```
export class GetDataFromREST() {

     constructor(private http: HttpClient, private loginStore: Store) {
          this.loggedIn$ = this.loginStore.select(getLoggedIn);
     }
     ...
     public getProducts(): Observable<ProductList> {

          return /*observable that returns http.get(api) only 
                   after the loggedIn$ emits true */
     }
}
```

Note that logging in should not be a concern of the service - once logged in it should execute all calls that were asked from it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by *"execute all calls that were asked from it."*?

Comment: I misunderstood your requirements - why not just to a bool check (isLoggedIn) in the  getProducts() method, and then either call the API or return an empty observable

Comment: If the app issues a call to `getProducts()` before the `IsLoggedIn` is set to `true` in the store, the call shouldn't fail (or return empty). It should wait until the value gets `true` and then return the `http.get` to the caller. I hope this clarifies it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will achieve your requested result.

```
export class GetDataFromREST() {

     constructor(private http: HttpClient, private loginStore: Store) {
          this.loggedIn$ = this.loginStore.select(getLoggedIn);
     }
     ...
     public getProducts(): Observable<ProductList> {

          return this.loggedIn$.filter(Boolean).take(1).subscribe(
            () => http.get(api)
          )
     }
}
```

Comment: This would call every `http.get` that was ever issued every time the store changes (which is quite frequently in redux)

Comment: Nice one... and simple! Works like a charm - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since `loggedIn$` is already an Observable you can replay it's last value and use it as a source Observable that will be merged with the remote call:

```
this.loggedIn$ = this.loginStore.select(getLoggedIn)
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount();

...

public getProducts(): Observable<ProductList> {
  return this.loggedIn$
    .mergeMap(() => http.get(api));
}
```

So `getProducts()` won't emit anything until the `this.loginStore.select(getLoggedIn)` emits.

Also when you call `getProducts()` later the latest value in `this.loggedIn$` will be replayed so it'll run the remote call immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the log in observable with the get api observable using the CombineLatest operator, then you can filter by logged in state

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html

Comment: If we do `return this.loggedIn$.combineLatest( ... );` wouldn't this emit an http call every time the store gets updated?